# Count every rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

i tried to count the value of every rows in MYSQL. But it only count the first row only. Can someone assist

First Query:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM [TEST].[dbo].[TEST3]
```

Result:

```
A   B   C
7   8   9
1   2   NULL
1   3   4
1   NULL    1
```

Count every rows but only the first row appear as result.
Query

```
SELECT COUNT (A + B + C)
FROM [TEST].[dbo].[TEST3]
```

Result:

```
2
```

It supposed to be `7+8+9 = 22` 
`1+2+NULL = 3`

etc.

Comment: Tag changed to SQL Server as the syntax is clearly not MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Just take the sum of the columns directly:

```
SELECT A, B, C,
    COALESCE(A, 0) + COALESCE(B, 0) COALESCE(C, 0) AS total
FROM [TEST].[dbo].[TEST3]
```

The reason why your current query using `COUNT` returns a single row is that `COUNT` is an aggregate function.  In the absence of `GROUP BY`, you are telling SQL Server to return a count over the entire table.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
SELECT IFNULL(A,0)+IFNULL(B,0)+IFNULL(C,0)
FROM [TEST].[dbo].[TEST3]
```

You do not want to use `COUNT()` here. `COUNT()` is an aggregate function. It output once per group. In your case, the whole query will output only one value.

Moreover, adding `NULL` to anything will be `NULL` and `COUNT()` will ignore that. Therefore the output of your query is 2.

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT()` is a aggregate function which will return group result.

The result is actually correct since `1 + 2 + NULL = NULL`, not `3`.

```
SELECT COUNT (A + B + C) FROM [TEST].[dbo].[TEST3]
```

Returns `2` because `COUNT()` will count only *non-null* value. If you run the query without `COUNT()` it will return 4 rows.

```
SELECT A + B + C FROM [TEST].[dbo].[TEST3]
```

The result is

```
24
NULL
8
NULL
```

However, if you wanted to return rows considering `NULL` as 0, you can use `COALESCE` within the columns,

```
SELECT COALESCE(A, 0) + COALESCE(B, 0) + COALESCE(C, 0) 
FROM [TEST].[dbo].[TEST3]
```

will now return

```
24
3
8
2
```

And when you write it with count, it will now return 4.

```
SELECT COUNT(COALESCE(A, 0) + COALESCE(B, 0) + COALESCE(C, 0) )
FROM [TEST].[dbo].[TEST3]
```

Result:

```
4
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/05fa8/2).

Comment: Thanks. Very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   A, B, C,
   Total = A + B+ C
FROM dbo.TEST
```

DO NOT USE COUNT.